# How to understand that the object was destroyed?

Tags: c++

I have some code:

```
void some_function(object *o)
{
    some_other_function(o);
    /* some actions with o */
}
```

All's good, but in some cases `some_other_function` can destroy `o`. How can i check it in `some_function` to avoid Segmentation Fault?

I think that the object is set to `NULL` but check it from the debugger, I realized that it's not.

Comment: Bad luck: you can't. That's why it is so important to think about ownership beforehand.

Comment: Can you change `some_other_function()`?

Comment: @freakish so sad(

Comment: The *documentation* should tell you what `some_other_function()` does. If it destroys the object randomly it should let you know by some means. Modern code should never delete raw pointers, their targets should be managed by smart pointers or containers - or otherwise by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no way to tell if the memory was freed and relevant object was destroyed. You will just get invalid pointer.

For exactly this purpose, I can recommend you few work-arounds, but before that I think you should read more about how C++ works.

`object *o`, which is passed to the function is just a copy of the pointer to the object, so when object is deleted pointer will become invalid, outside of the function no modifications to that pointer will be visible.

```
void some_other_function(object *o) {
      delete o;
      o = nullptr; // Copy of the pointer to the o was set to nullptr.
}

void some_function(object *o)
{
    some_other_function(o);
    if(o == nullptr) {
       //Code inside here will not be ever executed.
    }
    /* some actions with o */
}
```

But, if you pass pointer reference

```
void some_other_function(object &*o) {
      delete o;
      o = nullptr; // o is the reference to pointer, so outside of the function modification will be visible.
}
```

Function calee will see, that `o` became `nullptr`.

This is one pattern, another will be using smart pointers `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or using return value to indicate deletion.

```
if(!some_other_function(o)) {
// Object was deleted
}
```

Comment: I have to point out that this is a bad practice to free memory you haven't allocated, i.e. `some_other_function` should never do `delete` unless (1) it actually did `new` or (2) it is a method of some object that owns the pointer. Otherwise you risk getting into lots of trouble because the caller may not be aware that `some_other_function` does delete.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to read the source code (or, if not available, the documentation) for `some_other_function`.  And even that may not be enough in some cases.  There is no way to know just by looking at a pointer if that pointer points to something valid.

This is yet another reason you should use smart pointers for all owning pointers.  If `some_function` and `some_other_function` both accepted their parameter as `std::unique_ptr<object>` then you would (assuming your functions are well-behaved) know that the object pointed to is destroyed by `some_other_function`.  Similarly, if they accepted a `std::shared_ptr<object>` as their parameter, you would know that the object was still alive after the call to `some_other_function`.  Having clear ownership semantics is one of the keys to writing safe code, and smart pointers are a huge help in defining those ownership semantics.

Comment: Even if you read the source code it still may be impossible to determine that. For example consider when `some_other_function` deletes the object at random (or based on some other nondeterministic mechanism).

Comment: @freakish Added a sentence to address that.

Answer (score 0):

In 2018, I would adwise to use smart pointers. 
If you can't use smart pointers, design your code so that objects ownership is clearly defined. You should not have functions that may or may not delete an object, that's not a good practise and will bite you.
For the sake of completenes, but again i am not recommending to do so in any way, you may just let the function return a bool which indicates if the object has been destroyed or not.